# TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined React class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, frontend

I'm new to React and I am creating class components. I'm currently using the componentDidMount() function to fetch some JSON to use in the component but when I save the file I get an error. please could someone tell me where I am going wrong? [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5odE.png)

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac2xL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the class declaration, change `component` to first upper

`... extends React.Component` with a capital C